# Javascript: Creating Multiple Li Items with Button Onclick Function

Tags: javascript, html, button, html-lists

I am trying to create an application to display a certain number of list items based on the number input (i.e 3 = 3 list items). So far I have only been able to create a function that displays one list item with the onClick function. No matter what code I use, I cannot find a way to create multiple list items from one button click. Here is my current code, HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <section>
       <header>Week 5 Assignment</header>
       <section>
           <label>Name: <input type="text" id="nameInput" value="Enter a Name"></label>
       </section>
    <section>
        <label>Num of Times: <input type="number" id="numInput" value="Enter Number"></label>
        <section>
           <ol id="nameOutput"></ol>
           <hr>
          <button onclick="displayName();">Display Name!</button> 
          <button>Reset</button> 
       </section>
    </section>
   </section>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JS:

```
    var name = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
    console.log(name);

    var num = document.getElementById("numInput").value;

    var list = document.getElementById("nameOutput");

    var item = document.createElement("li");

    item.innerText = name;
    list.append(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript For loop should work for what you are trying to achieve

```html
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <section>
           <header>Week 5 Assignment</header>
           <section>
               <label>Name: <input type="text" id="nameInput" value="Enter a Name"></label>
           </section>
        <section>
            <label>Num of Times: <input type="number" id="numInput" value="Enter Number"></label>
            <section>
               <ol id="nameOutput"></ol>
               <hr>
              <button onclick="displayName();">Display Name!</button> 
              <button>Reset</button> 
           </section>
        </section>
       </section>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script>
    function displayName() {
        var name = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;

        var num = document.getElementById("numInput").value;

        var item = document.createElement("li");

        item.innerText = name;
        
        document.getElementById("nameOutput").innerHTML = '';

        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        document.getElementById("nameOutput").innerHTML += '<li>'+name+'</li>';
        }
        
    }
    </script>
```